# Select Default Option - Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following code, based on Bootstrap 4:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2">Choose from: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>Opt 1</option>
      <option>Opt 2</option>
      <option>Opt 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result in the screenshot below:

[image]

But I wish to have **Opt 2** selected by default ***without*** changing the order of the options. Preferably without additional javascript also. How?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the attribute `selected` to the `<option selected>Opt 2</option>`